# same pci bus address for pci slot and on board ethernet port?

Tags: ethernet, pci-express, pci, gigabit-ethernet, pci-x

The pci slot address shown is same as the one shown for on board ethernet card. There is a conflict. Not sure how to resolve it.

Various command output are

```
 dmidecode -t 9 | grep 'Bus Address'

    Bus Address: 0000:08:00.0
    Bus Address: 0000:04:00.0
    Bus Address: 0000:05:00.1


lspci|grep 'Gigabit'
09:00.0 Ethernet controller:  <card name >
0a:00.0 Ethernet controller:  <card manufacturer name>

 biosdecode|egrep 'slot'


    Slot Entry 8: ID 0a:00, slot number 24
    Slot Entry 17: ID 0b:01, slot number 34
    Slot Entry 18: ID 02:00, slot number 4
```

we can see that slot entry 8 has same pci bus address 0a:00 which is same as for on board ethernet controller.

Not sure why is it showing or how to fix this issue? If I change the pci card slot will it do any good? What should be doing next to resolve the issue ?

Comment: Are you having a real problem here or are you just getting nonsensical information reported from the BIOS?